# How to change Pandas DataFrame date index from daily to hourly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas Dataframe with a datetime index grained daily, I want to repeat each row for each hour in the day so that my Dataframe is now grained hourly.

From

```
2010-01-01  |  150
2010-01-02  |  200
```

To

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00 |  150
2010-01-01 01:00:00 |  150
2010-01-01 02:00:00 |  150
.
.
.
2010-01-01 23:00:00 |  150
2010-01-02 00:00:00 |  200
2010-01-02 01:00:00 |  200
.
.
.
2010-01-02 23:00:00 |  200
```

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.date_range.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.resample('H').ffill()`. Documentation links: [User Guide/Timeseries/Resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).

[image]

### Updated example with period index

[image]

Comment: There is problem with last row, missing hours

Comment: You mean since it stops at 00:00, and you want the entire day?

Comment: To fix that, you can change to index to a period index before doing the resampling: `df.to_period().resample('H').ffill()`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help and the update

Answer (score 0):

First create `DatetimeIndex` if necessary:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Create all possible hours datetimes by `date_range` and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'), freq='H')
df2 = df.reindex(rng, method='ffill')
```

---

```
print (df2)
                       A
2010-01-01 00:00:00  150
2010-01-01 01:00:00  150
2010-01-01 02:00:00  150
2010-01-01 03:00:00  150
2010-01-01 04:00:00  150
2010-01-01 05:00:00  150
2010-01-01 06:00:00  150
2010-01-01 07:00:00  150
2010-01-01 08:00:00  150
2010-01-01 09:00:00  150
2010-01-01 10:00:00  150
2010-01-01 11:00:00  150
2010-01-01 12:00:00  150
2010-01-01 13:00:00  150
2010-01-01 14:00:00  150
2010-01-01 15:00:00  150
2010-01-01 16:00:00  150
2010-01-01 17:00:00  150
2010-01-01 18:00:00  150
2010-01-01 19:00:00  150
2010-01-01 20:00:00  150
2010-01-01 21:00:00  150
2010-01-01 22:00:00  150
2010-01-01 23:00:00  150
2010-01-02 00:00:00  200
2010-01-02 01:00:00  200
2010-01-02 02:00:00  200
2010-01-02 03:00:00  200
2010-01-02 04:00:00  200
2010-01-02 05:00:00  200
2010-01-02 06:00:00  200
2010-01-02 07:00:00  200
2010-01-02 08:00:00  200
2010-01-02 09:00:00  200
2010-01-02 10:00:00  200
2010-01-02 11:00:00  200
2010-01-02 12:00:00  200
2010-01-02 13:00:00  200
2010-01-02 14:00:00  200
2010-01-02 15:00:00  200
2010-01-02 16:00:00  200
2010-01-02 17:00:00  200
2010-01-02 18:00:00  200
2010-01-02 19:00:00  200
2010-01-02 20:00:00  200
2010-01-02 21:00:00  200
2010-01-02 22:00:00  200
2010-01-02 23:00:00  200
```

Comment: I already have a datetime index so I think the first two rows are not important. I got `Cannot convert input [2010-01-01 00:00:00] of type <class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> to Timestamp`  as an error, looking into it at the moment

Comment: @LotsOfQuestions - Is possible convert index values `DatetimeGregorian` to strings and then to pandas datetimes?

Comment: I indeed got it doing `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.map(str)))`. Probably an easier way out there !

Comment: While your solution works, the one above is exactly what I needed in a concise way. Thank you!